# Что означает "собака @" перед переменной?

Tags: ruby

Читаю-читаю документацию, вики прочитал на русском и английском, что означает собака (`@`) для переменных - не понимаю.

Например, `counter` объявлю с двумя собаками, с одной собакой и без собаки:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby


@@counter = 0
@counter = 0
counter = 0

for i in 1..5
        print "@@counter = ", @@counter, "\n"
        @@counter = @@counter + 1
end

for i in 1..10
        print "@counter = ", @counter, "\n"
        @counter = @counter + 1
end

for i in 1..15
        print "counter = ", counter, "\n"
        counter = counter + 1
end

print "\n"
print "@@counter = ", @@counter, "\n"
print "@counter = ", @counter, "\n"
print "counter = ", counter, "\n"
```

результат:

```
@@counter = 0
@@counter = 1
@@counter = 2
@@counter = 3
@@counter = 4
@counter = 0
@counter = 1
@counter = 2
@counter = 3
@counter = 4
@counter = 5
@counter = 6
@counter = 7
@counter = 8
@counter = 9
counter = 0
counter = 1
counter = 2
counter = 3
counter = 4
counter = 5
counter = 6
counter = 7
counter = 8
counter = 9
counter = 10
counter = 11
counter = 12
counter = 13
counter = 14

@@counter = 5
@counter = 10
counter = 15
```

Получается что это **ТРИ** РАЗНЫХ переменных? Какая-то из них `глобальнее`, чем другая?

> The sigils $ and @ do not indicate variable data type as in Perl, but rather function as scope resolution operators.

В википедии https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29

А на три собаки, почему-то ругается

```
$ ruby dogs.rb
dogs.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
@@@counter = 0
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Нет, мне до сих пор не дан верный ответ. Я не могу понять в чём ТРИ разницы между этими переменными.

Answer (score 4):

Переменные, начинающиеся с `@` - это переменные экземпляра класса. [Class and Instance Variables In Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) (или [объяснение на русском](http://habrahabr.ru/post/48756/))

Весь код Ruby исполняется в контексте какого-то объекта, даже если это обычный скрипт. В этом случае Ruby создает объект верхнего уровня "main" и в нём исполняется весь ваш код:

```
[1] pry(main)> @counter = 1
=> 1
[2] pry(main)> self
=> main
[3] pry(main)> self.instance_variables
=> [:@counter]
```

Изучать возможности Ruby удобно с помощью gem-а [pry](http://pryrepl.org/). Считайте, что это команды, которые выполняются в скрипте. Первой командой я создал переменную экземпляра класса @counter, второй командой я вывел контекст (это как раз объект "main") и третьей командой я вывел все переменные текущего объекта - как вы видите, там одна переменная - @counter

Три собаки - недопустимая конструкция, поэтому и ругается.

Comment: Смотри, я чуть-чуть добавил вопрос. Но у меня то нет никакого класса, простой скрипт по-шаговый...

Comment: @rubyboy я дополнил ответ, надеюсь, что вам всё понятно.

Comment: а две собаки что значит? Что это такое-то? Я никак не могу понять.

Comment: Вы читали первую ссылку? Там достаточно подробно всё разжевано.

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно переменные, начинающиеся с @, являются переменными именно экземпляра класса. Хотя чаще используются именно как переменные экземпляра класса.
В руби 2.1.2 @@ тоже не считается глобальной переменной, вместо @@ - $.
Вот пример:

```
class Klass
  @counter = 0
  $counter = 100

  def self.class_increment
    @counter = @counter + 1
    return @counter
  end

  def self.global_increment
    $counter = $counter + 1
    return $counter
  end
end


class Klass2
  @counter = 0

  def self.class_increment
    @counter = @counter + 1
    return @counter
  end

  def self.global_increment
    $counter = $counter + 1
    return $counter
  end
end
```

Если вызывать `Klass.class_increment` и `Klass2.class_increment`, то можно заметить, что переменная `@counter` увеличивается только в пределах одного класса. А если `Klass.global_increment` и `Klass2.global_increment`, то инкрементируется именно переменная `$counter`, которая является глобальной и до которой всегда есть write/read доступ.

Переменные без $ или @ - это переменные "здесь и сейчас". Они доступны в рамках одного уровня (метода или объекта).
Вот попробуй выполнить в консоли:

```
class Klass
  counter = 0
  p counter

  def get_conter
    counter
  end
end
Klass.new.get_conter
```

Comment: Зачем вы пишите return в конце метода?

Comment: Переменные "здесь и сейчас" называются локальными переменными.

Comment: да, можно и не писать, для наглядности